# Finding maximum count of a specific column in hive

Tags: sql, hive

My table in Hive:

```
liked                   string                                      
user_id                 int                                         
video_end_type          int                                         
minutes_played          int                                         
video_id                int                                         
geo_cd                  string                                      
channel_id              int                                         
creator_id              int                                         
time                    timestamp                                   
disliked                string
```

Query: Fetch the most popular channels by the criteria of a maximum number of videos played, also liked by unique users.

Output: It should include the columns – channel id, total distinct videos played, count of distinct
users

Comment: what do you mean by most popular? you need only one channel id with max number of videos played ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distinct count of video_id and user_id will not ensure the asked condition - "maximum number of videos played, also liked by unique users." assuming that in a channel there could be a video_id but not necessary that has been played. So, the column minutes_played is something we can take to which tells us - a video has been played. Something like below will help- further you can use a query to select the desired column

```
WITH cte as(
count(cast(minutes_played as double)) as video_played_count,
count(liked) as liked
FROM T
GROUP BY channel_id
ORDER BY video_played_count desc
)
SELECT
count(distinct video_id) as total_distinct_videos,
count(distinct user_id) as total_distinct_users
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN
T
ON cte.channel_id = T.channel_id
GROUP BY channel_id
ORDER BY total_distinct_videos desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `count` and `group by`. You can use `limit` to get number of top channels.

```
select
  channel_id,
  count(distinct video_id) as total_distinct_videos,
  count(distinct user_id) as total_distinct_users
from myTable
group by
  channel_od
order by
  total_distinct_videos desc
limit 5      <---- this will give top 5 channels
```